# How to compare two set of PMFs?

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, density-function, distance, mixture-distribution

I'm facing some challenge and I don't know the correct approach for this.
I'm having two sets of PMFs $S_1, S_2$ and I need to compare (distance like Jensen–Shannon) $S_1$ with $S_2$.
What's the best away to do that? I'm thinking to calculate the mixture of $S_1$ and $S_2$ or the convolution of them and then use the right metric. Is the element-wise comparison between those sets better?

EDIT:

In other words, I'm have the finite set $S_1 = \{a_1, a_2, \ldots\}$ and $S_2 = \{b_1, b_2, \ldots\}$, $a_i$ and $b_i$ are PMFs. So, I want a tool to compare $S_1$ with $S_2$. My first thinking is to gather all PMFs into $S_1$ in another PMF $O_1$ and gather all PMFs into $S_2$ in another PMF $O_2$. How do I will gather this PMFs? Through mixture or convolutions? Is this the best approach?

EDIT2:

I'm trying to model a fairness algorithm, and I'm trying to check if some behavior occurs in set S1, for example, Women, and do not occur in S2, the set of men PMFs. The algorithm outputs for each individual a PMF. I can group those individuals into set S1 and S2 and I want to compare them.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe Kullback-Leibler Divergence?

Comment: @igorkf I can use this to compare two PMFs, but I want to compare a set of PMFs to another set of PMFs.

Comment: @Xi'an For example, divergence between distributions.

Comment: @Xi'an Sorry, maybe my explanation is a little bit confusing. I'm have the finite set $S_1 = \{a_1, a_2, \ldots\}$ and $S_2 = \{b_1, b_2, \ldots\}$, $a_i$ and $b_i$ are PMFs. So, I want a tool to compare $S_1$ with $S_2$. My first thinking is to gather all PMFs into $S_1$ in another PMF $O_1$ and gather all PMFs into $S_2$ in another PMF $O_2$. How do I will gather this PMFs? Through mixture or convolutions? Is this the best approach?

Comment: Can you tell us what is the **ultimate** purpose?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Off course, I'm trying to model a fairness algorithm, and I'm trying to check if some behavior occurs in set $S_1$, for example, Women, and do not occur in $S_2$, the set of men PMFs. The algorithm outputs for each individual a PMF. I can group those individuals into set $S_1$ and $S_2$ and I want to compare them. Sorry, am I clear?

Comment: Can you please add that explication to the post as an edit? Not everybody reads comments!

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen done, thank you.